# Voiceover overriding for UIbarButtonItem

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, voiceover

I am trying to do custom voice over for `UIBarButtonItem` . Although it is reading the `accessibilityValue` it is also reading the name of the image set for `UIBarButtonItem`.

```
sidebarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
sidebarButton.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
sidebarButton.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
[sidebarButton setAccessibilityValue:@"Checking Something"];
```

So the voiceover is reading "Menu Checking Something Button". Although I want it to read only "Checking Something".

**Note** Disabling accessiblity for image doesn't work.        `sidebarButton.image.isAccessibilityElement = NO;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setAccessibilityLabel` instead of `setAccessibilityValue` solves the problem